# Why Python shows two different lists for list(str(z)) method

Tags: python, string, list

I type following code

```
z=1+2j
z=list(str(z))
```

I get output as

```
 ['(','1','+','2','j',')']
```

but when I write the following code

```
 z=input('')
 z=list(str(z))
 print(z)
```

I get output as

```
['1','+','2','j']
```

and not the curve brackets in the list why?

Comment: Because in the first case, `z` is a complex number. In the second, it is a string.

Comment: your question is not clear. how do you want it to look like ?

Comment: In second case too in input I entered 1+2j .So you are saying that it becomes string ? and that's why it showed no brackets. I just wanted to have same list in both the cases.

Comment: It's kind of strange to want a list of single chars for this anyways; if someone entered `-0.3-1.2j` would you want something like `['-', '0', '.', '3' ...]` or it split up more logically like `['-', '0.3', '-', '1.2', 'j']`?

Comment: second one seems more logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `input()`, you entered 4 characters: `1`,`+`,`2`,`j`.  Together, they may have the same semantic value to you as the number `1+2j`, but as far as Python is concerned, the former case is just four characters.  Python doesn't have any way of knowing you think those characters should be converted to a single numerical value.

You can observe the differences with a few `print` statements.
And you can explicitly *declare* that this four-character string should be interpreted as a complex number, with `complex()`:

```
a = input('') # input: "1+2j"

print(a) # i+2j
print(type(a)) # <class 'str'>


b = complex(a)
print(b) # (1+2j)
print(type(b)) # <class 'complex'>
```

Comment: will it be okay to say that python uses the braces just to differentiate between a string and a complex?

Comment: yes, that's how those two datatypes are visually differentiated when they are printed.  the braces themselves are not required to signal complex numbers to python, though - `1 + 2j` and `(1 + 2j)` are equivalent.  python just uses the braces for printed notation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant:

z = "1+2j"

Answer (score 0):

When you typed the code

```
z=1+2j
z=list(str(z))
```

Type of z is *complex*.  Calling the function str on it will simply give you what `__str__` function of class `complex` returns.  In your case, `str(z)` would return

> '(1+2j)'

When you do `z=list(str(z))`, it gives you a list of all the characters in `str(z)`.  Now z points to a list not to a complex object.

When you run this

```
 z=input('')
 z=list(str(z))
 print(z)
```

`input('')` gives you a str type value.  Whatever you enter here is converted to the list when you call `z=list(str(z))`.